# PHP Zip function doesn't work (Debian, Apache, PHP5)

Tags: php, apache, zip, debian

I've installed apache on a debian server and added php. But if i try to create a .zip file it doesn't work. There's no error message but the .zip file doesn't get created.

Code:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('Banner1.png', 'Banner1.png');
$zip->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are the parenthesis after ZipArchive optional in PHP?

Comment: @Patrick Do you see any messages in the apache error log?

Comment: Where can i see the error log?

Comment: `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log`

Comment: No errors for this php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the user that php is running as (on debian, `www-data` by default) doesn't have writing permissions to the directory. Check the result of the various functions like this:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if (!$res){
    echo 'Error while creating zip file: ' . $zip->getStatusString();
    exit();
}
if (! $zip->addFile('Banner1.png', 'Banner1.png')) {
    echo 'Error while adding Banner1: ' . $zip->getStatusString();
    exit();
}
if (! $zip->close()) {
    echo 'Error while closing: ' . $zip->getStatusString();
    exit();
}
```

On a debian with default configuraiton, you can configure permissions with [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod). For example, to allow the webserver to write to that directory, try

```
sudo chown www-data /path/to/directory/with/php/file
sudo chmod u+rwx /path/to/directory/with/php/file
```

Comment: Error while closing: Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied

But how can i enable that?

Comment: @Patrick Yup, that's precisely the message you get when you don't have the necessary access rights, just like I suspected. Amended the answer with two exemplary commands to allow the webserver/php to write to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sûre your $res is good ?

```
if ($res === TRUE) {
    echo 'ok';
    $zip->addFile('Banner1.png', 'Banner1.png');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
}
```